# Dynamically change outerHeight using Javascript/jQuery without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, margin

I am trying to dynamically change the marginTop of `#mainPart`, which is the section right after `nav` item with `navbar-fixed-top` class.

The problem I am having is that with this function, I must refresh the page for the changes to happen - for the margin to be set. But, I want it to happen with `Submit` button pressed. `Submit` button does not refresh the page and it just outputs data based on the the queried keyword results. `Submit` button itself in HTML has `ng-click` with `do_Submit` function.

I have created below function and added it to `do_Submit` function, but it only works when I refresh the page, instead of when I press `Submit` button

```
$(window).load(function() {
  maxHeight = $('#main-navbar').outerHeight();
  alert("Height of main-navbar: " + maxHeight);
  $('#mainPart').css({ marginTop : maxHeight + 5 + 'px' }); 
});
```

Note than `#main-navbar` is the ID for the `nav` part in HTML and `#mainPart` is the ID for the part right after `nav` part.

My submit button's HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" tooltip ng-click="submit(query)" title="<p>Query sentences</p>"><span ></span> Submit</button>
```

What can I do to dynamically change the marginTop without refreshing the page?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you add a minimal example with the html markup required for this to test?

Comment: I can’t see how you have added the function to the submit button, please could you show us.

Comment: The code you wrote above is put inside jQuery's `.load` function, which obviously only will execute when the page loads.

Comment: Sorry,I am new to front-end dev.But, to explain better what I have:I have nav section that has navbar-fixed-top class.This section shows the inputted query as text (after I hit submit button).Then, table shows up below nav section based on the query. If I query longer sentences,then nav section's height increases, as queried sentences appears as text in this nav section.Once the height of this nav section increases,it covers the top part of the table,so the first element cannot be seen.That's why I am trying to dynamically change the top-margin of this table based on the height of nav section.

Comment: @Mohi , is there any other function I could use for it not to require the page to be reloaded? Also, I am going to show submit function I am using for submit button in a few. Trying to update my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always add

```
$('#mainPart').css({ marginTop : maxHeight + 5 + 'px' });
```

to another event listener for the submit button. I don't know the do_Submit function, but if that button is just an html element, then select it in the JS and add that CSS change to the button's own event listener, rather than on page load.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

Yes, found the event listener in do_Submit. It was basically an HTTP request with post method. I put those two lines that calculates and changes the margintop inside of .success function - the function that outputs the graphs if HTTP request was succeeded.  Thank you!